# Using SQL"load data" in workbench and fill the file name to column

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

Since I'm using workbench and want to load the text file data.
And I would like to add file name in column.

Let me giving you my example.

My text file: 20170205077.txt

Data in "20170205077.txt":

```
1|Something|Something_2, 1|Something|Something_3
```

Also the query is

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "20170205077.txt" INTO "DB.TABLE"
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' Lines terminated by ', '
```

When executed I hope the table like this:

```
| FileName |userId| data   | data  |
|20170205077|  1  |Something|Something_2|
|20170205077|  1  |Something|Something_3|
```

How to enhance the query?

Comment: I think that the best you can do in this situation is to create a procedure that will receive the file name as a parameter and inside it you load the data and then fill the fileName field (just guessing a probable solution since I don't know if mysql allows load data inside a procedure). In order to it to work you will need to have a field to identify the current process so when you update those loaded lines you know from which file they belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bat file: (ex. upload.bat)
Put it and all your text files in C:\import (name of folder and files must not have SPACE). Then run the bat file to import

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR %%f IN ("*.txt") DO (
  set old=%%~dpnxf
  set new=!old:\=\\!
  "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql" -e "load data local infile '"!new!"' IGNORE into table DB.TABLE (userID, data1, data2) FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"""' LINES TERMINATED BY ',' SET Filename = %%nf" -h yourhost -u youruser -pYourpassword YourDB
  echo UPLOAD %%~nxf DONE
)

pause
```